# Power BI - Cannot figure out DAX logic to show dynamic last 6 months data as a tooltip

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a finance PowerBI report that I'm trying to enhance, but struggling on this particular tooltip. Hopefully someone more knowledgable than me can help me out :)

Ok here's the relevant data model setup:

Table Name: "**Date**"

```
| Date        | Month Year   |
|:----------- |:------------:|
| 01/01/2022  | January 2022 |
| 02/01/2022  | January 2022 |
| 03/01/2022  | January 2022 |
etc.
```

Table Name: "**Categories**"

```
| Category            |
|:------------------- |
| Household Shopping  |
| Bills               |
| Mortgage / Rent     |
| Motoring            |
| Payslip             |
| Income              |
etc.
```

Table Name: "**Transactions**"

```
| Date        | Transaction      | Category           | Amount |
|:----------- |:-----------------|:-------------------|:-------|
| 05/01/2022  | Mortgage Payment | Mortgage / Rent    | -£1000 |
| 05/01/2022  | Electricity Bill | Bills              | -£80   |
| 08/01/2022  | Salary           | Payslip            | £2500  |
| 11/01/2022  | Grocery Shopping | Household Shopping | -£45   |
| 12/01/2022  | DIY Store        | Household Shopping | -£170  |
| 12/01/2022  | Car Fuel         | Motoring           | -£80   |
etc.
```

And the model is Date --> Transactions <-- Category

I have a report that shows a snapshot of my finances and spending on a monthly basis, so there's a dropdown slicer at the top of the page where I can change the month (Date[Month Year]) and all the visuals update to show relevant data for that particular month.

I have these measures to calculate my earnings and spending:

```
Earnings =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Transactions[Amount] ),
    OR ( Transactions[Category] = "Payslip", Transactions[Category] = "Income" )
)

Spending =
( -1 )
    * CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Transactions[Amount] ),
        Transactions[Category] <> "Payslip",
        Transactions[Category] <> "Income"
    )

Spending % of Earnings =
DIVIDE ( [Spending], CALCULATE ( [Earnings], ALL ( Categories ) ) )
```

On this page I have 2 bar charts that shows my spending for each category. These both have the y-axis as Categories[Category] and the value as the "Spending" and "Spending & of Earnings" measures respectively.
So far all works well.

Here's where I'm getting stuck. When I hover over the various bars, I would like to see a tooltip that shows a column/line chart of those measures over the past 6 months. For example if I selected June 2022 in the page slicer, I'd like the tooltip to show the spending measures for Jan 2022 - June 2022.

I've managed to get a tooltip that shows data for the past 6 months, and think it works for the 'Spending' measure. But for the life of me I can't get the 'Spending % of Earnings' working. I assume there's some combination of DAX to do it but I'm struggling.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: did you try this?

DIVIDE ( CALCULATE ( [Spending], ALL ( Categories )), CALCULATE ( [Earnings], ALL ( Categories ) ) )

Comment: and why didnt you add **OR ( ** to the spending ?

Comment: sorry that measure doesn't work. The numerator needs to calculate based on the category that is selected, but the denominator needs to calculate earnings for all categories. For some reason the tooltip value always calculates this for the selected category as well